# I don't know why my contract have a problem. Gas estimation and Gas exceeds Problem

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas-estimate

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.24 <=0.5.6;

contract Indian {
    mapping (address => uint16) myGame;
    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }


    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function deposit() payable external {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
    }

    function buyGame(uint _gamePrice) payable public returns (bool) {
        require(getBalance() >= _gamePrice);
        msg.sender.transfer(_gamePrice);
        myGame[msg.sender]++;
        return true;
    }

    function getMyGame() view external returns(uint16) {
        return myGame[msg.sender];
    }

    function sellMyGame(uint _gamePrice) payable external {
        uint refund = (myGame[msg.sender] * _gamePrice);
        myGame[msg.sender] = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(refund);
    }
    function investGame() payable external {
        myGame[msg.sender]++;
    }

}
```

My Gas Limit is 3000000.

Why my contract has a gas exceed problem?

Comment: What are you doing that cause that error? Trying it remix it works as expected.